# Unable to create partition on Mariadb on this child table where Foreign Key Exists?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.1, mariadb-connect-engine

Unable to create partition this child table "city" with parent table "country" It is showing below error "Foreign Key Not Supported". Without foreign key how relation maintain

ForeignKey not supported by partition]
[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIlQR.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpjOv.png

Comment: And what is unclear in error message? Partitioning and foreign key presence are not compatible. Either the former or the latter, not both.

Comment: Just click on the image url

Comment: ForeignKey clause is not supported in conjunction with portioning.  I try to partitioning on a table where foreign key is available. I want to partition that table by keeping ForeignKey. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning tables with `FOREIGN KEY` is not supported in MariaDB.

According to the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitioning-limitations):

- A partitioned table cannot contain, or be referenced
  by, foreign keys.
- All columns used in the
  partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every
  unique key that the table may have.
- Each table can contain a maximum of 8192 partitions (from MariaDB
  10.0.4). In MariaDB 5.5 and until 10.0.3, the limit was 1024.

As an alternative to Foreign Keys you could use Triggers to update the partitioned table when a parent table changes.

Recent versions of PostgreSQL do support Foreign Keys for Partitioned Tables. If that is important to you, you might want to have a look there.

Comment: Yes I know this issue but I could not able to create  trigger each time it said syntax error. I also try through this document (https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/12/26/using-referential-constraints-with-partitioned-tables-in-innodb/). If you have any better document please help me on this. Thanks in advance.